# Why doesn't InterlockedCompareExchange return changed value?

Tags: windows, winapi, synchronization, atomic, interlocked

```
LONG __cdecl InterlockedCompareExchange(
  __inout  LONG volatile *Destination,
  __in     LONG Exchange,
  __in     LONG Comparand
);
```

> **Return value**
>   The function returns the initial value of the Destination parameter.

Just curious.
Why does InterlockedCompareExchange return *initial* value? Is there a reason that they designed so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good example from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
    for(;;)
    {
        // calculate the function
        new_value = Random(old_value);

        // set the new value if the current value is still the expected one
        cur_value = InterlockedCompareExchange(seed, new_value, old_value);

        // we found the expected value: the exchange happened
        if(cur_value == old_value)
            break;

        // recalculate the function on the unexpected value
        old_value = cur_value;
    }
```

Do you see why it's important to be able to retain the initial value?

Comment: It would be better if you give me little more explanation. Anyway, I got it, finally. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Because this gives you the most information. If you only know the changed value and it happens to be equal to `Exchange`, the inital value could be `Exchange` or it could be `Comparand`.